# Unable to Preview audio/vnd.wave in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-5, wav, rails-activestorage

I am using

> active storage(5.2.5)

On **.wav** file uploading it shows content type as **'audio/wav'** in direct upload.  While using **mime magic gem**, after **active_storage_attachments** create it updates the content type as **audio/x-wav**. And this extension file **preview** in **chrome**.

But after changing to **marcel** it saves the content type as **'audio/vnd.wave'**. While debugging, **active_storage / blob / identifiable** updates the content types. And **'audio/vnd.wave'** not previewed in chrome but safari allows to preview.

So, tried to comment the lines related to update on **active_storage/blob/identifiable**. It saved the content type as **audio/x-wav** and allows it to preview in Chrome.

Tried to add configuration in **application.rb**

> config.active_storage.content_types_allowed_inline += %w[audio/wave
> audio/vnd.wave audio/wav audio/x-wav audio/x-pn-wav]

But not able to preview the **audio/vnd.wave** extension files in chrome.

Is chrome have the support to audio/vnd.wave extensions?

If chrome has the support, whether I need to add any other configuration to preview?

Hope understand my issue. Please help me to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not what you're looking for but since marcel gem is saving your files as `.wave`  did you try overriding that an extension configuration as `wav` instead of `wave`

you can do a `Marcel::Magic.add("audio/vnd", extensions: ["wav"])`